# Search within array of objects with formated ISOdate

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with an array of time objects and i want to get the records within the last day, but i can't seem to figure this out.

I'm new with mongodb and i have always worked with SQL so maybe that's in the way of solving this.

Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58eb9f8738505a28267a6cd6"),
    "times" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2017-04-13 14:16:47.000000",
            "timezone_type" : 1,
            "timezone" : "+00:00"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2017-04-10 14:16:47.000000",
            "timezone_type" : 1,
            "timezone" : "+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Awesome title",
    "user" : 1,
    "description" : " cool!",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-10T15:06:47.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-10T15:06:47.000Z")
}
```

And my mongodb query

```
db.getCollection('reminders').find({
        "times": {
            $elemMatch: { 
                "date": { 
                    $gte:  {                    
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%L",
                            date: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
})
```

Now i get "Error: Line 3: Unexpected token :" within the $dateToString object. 
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$dateToString` operator can only be used as an aggregation operator.

For a `find()` method usage, you will have to manipulate the date format yourself. There are several libraries which can do it, but it's also fairly easy to do it manually:

```
> var date = new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 1)
> date
ISODate("2017-04-13T17:47:49.666Z")
> var bound = date.toISOString().replace("T", " ").substr(0, 20).concat("000000")
> bound
2017-04-13 17:47:49.000000

db.getCollection('reminders').find({
    "times": { $elemMatch: { "date": {$gte:  bound} } }
})
```